# Using result from one query to as a WHERE clause

Tags: php, json, phpmyadmin

I am trying to get the postcode with one query and use it in the where clause for another query.

```
<?php
$mobile = '07790807055';
//$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];


mysql_connect("", "", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());

$query =("SELECT POSTCODE FROM appregistration WHERE MOBILE_NUMBER = '$mobile'");
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("Unable to connect. " . mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$postcode = $row['POSTCODE'];
/// gets postcode from appregistration table 

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT INCIDENT_ID, INVESTIGATION,TYPE_OF_INCIDENT,DESCRIPTION FROM appreports WHERE POSTCODE = '$postcode'");
//uses postcode from ppregistration table  to find info from appreports table 

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) $output[]=$row;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Assign your query to a string before the 2nd query and paste it here. `$query2 = "SELECT INCIDENT_ID, INVESTIGATION,TYPE_OF_INCIDENT,DESCRIPTION FROM appreports WHERE POSTCODE = '$postcode'"; echo $query2; $sql=mysql_query($query2);`

Comment: @mkaatman `$sql` will likely be a Resource, and not convertible to a string.

Comment: Once you this sorted, look up database joins.

Comment: thank you mkaatman , this is the output Resource id #4null

Comment: this was the output mkaarman "SELECT INCIDENT_ID, INVESTIGATION,TYPE_OF_INCIDENT,DESCRIPTION FROM appreports WHERE POSTCODE = 'CF14'null"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a `JOIN` rather than running two queries:

```
SELECT `INCIDENT_ID`, `INVESTIGATION`, `TYPE_OF_INCIDENT`, `DESCRIPTION`
FROM `appreports`
INNER JOIN `appregistration` ON `appreports`.`POSTCODE` = `appregistration`.`POSTCODE`
WHERE `appregistration`.`MOBILE_NUMBER` = '$mobile'
```

For example:

```
<?php
$mobile = '07790807055';

mysql_connect("", "", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `INCIDENT_ID`, `INVESTIGATION`, `TYPE_OF_INCIDENT`, `DESCRIPTION`
                    FROM `appreports`
                    INNER JOIN `appregistration` 
                    ON `appreports`.`POSTCODE` = `appregistration`.`POSTCODE`
                    WHERE `appregistration`.`MOBILE_NUMBER` = '$mobile'");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $output[] = $row;
}

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: this is the error i am getteing if i use join "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '`' on line 20

Comment: also i want the output in json as i am using it for my android app

Comment: I don't get the error here - are you sure you copied everything correctly? The output will still be of `json_encode`...

Comment: You should also be advised that `mysql_*` are deprecated and you should look into using `mysqli` as a minimum.

Comment: i coped everything , i get "null"

Comment: Then the records you're querying don't exist. What happens if you run the query directly on the DB?

Comment: THANKS for all the help , i found the problem , when i add new row in the database using sql it works , but when i use php it does not work haha

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the glaring SQL injection vulnerability, the dubious commenting (the redundant punctuation) in the code, the deprecated API and the reliance on default parameters in the call to mysql_fetch_array(), the unnecessary split query, and a few other things which should be picked up in any code review but which don't actually affect the functionality....You don't actually say what happens when you run the code.

Does the first query return a result?

What happens when you run the queries via the mysql CLI or phpmyadmin?

**UPDATE**

> this is the error i am getteing if i use join "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '`' on line 20

OK, it *is* a SQL injection bug that's causing the problem - I assume that this is line 20:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT INCIDENT_ID, INVESTIGATION,TYPE_OF_INCIDENT
      ,DESCRIPTION FROM appreports WHERE POSTCODE = '$postcode'");
```

$postcode contains one or more single quotes. Escape it:

```
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT INCIDENT_ID, INVESTIGATION,TYPE_OF_INCIDENT
      ,DESCRIPTION FROM appreports WHERE POSTCODE = '".
      mysql_real_escape_string($postcode) . "'");
```

Comment: THANKS for all the help , i found the problem , when i add new row in the database using sql it works , but when i use php it does not work haha